# p4passwd invalid or unset in git-p4 python

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

So I have my perforce and git set up. I can easily access, modify perforce with simple commands like "p4 info" etc from the command line. I have a perforce workspace and I created a new directory for git next to it. Whenever I try "git p4 clone //perforce/(path)" it gives me the error "Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset."

Now I tried a couple of different things. I tried using 
1)

```
export P4USER=(username)
export P4HOST, P4PASSWD etc.
```

2)Created a .perforce file in both perforce workspace and git directory which has 
"

```
P4CLIENT= xzy
P4USER= abc
P4HOST= asd
P4PORT= .."
 P4PASSWD= (here i tried the password and alternatively the key I got by using p4 login -p )
```

3)Made a .gitconfig file in the git directory with similar variables.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but whatever I do, git p4 always fails due to this P4PASSWD issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Forgot to add, I'm using Windows

Comment: I've noticed P4PORT does not work .. try P4HOST=host:port

Comment: Try `p4 login` (without `-p`).  Ensure that you've set `P4PORT`, `P4USER`, `P4CLIENT`.  `P4PORT` is of the form `server:port`.

Comment: Thanks guys but I had port in the form xyz.perforce.com:1666 but I don't know why it didn't work. Should it work if I just set them up using p4 set command or would I have a specific file. I'm getting the feeling that I should have some config file which I'm missing. Do you guys mind telling me your directory layout?

Answer (score 0):

First execute `p4 login` to cache your credentials.